# Replace all values of row with Frequent value of a row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
Index  Parameters   A    B   C   D   E
1      Apple        1    2   3   4   5
2      Banana       2    4   5   3   5
3      Potato       3    5   3   2   1
4      Tomato       1    1   1   1   1
5      Pear         $4    $5   $5   $5   $3
```

**Problem statement**:

Based on the value of `Parameters` column and row `Pear` I want to get the most frequent value and replace with all the values

**Output df**:

```
Index  Parameters   A    B   C   D   E
1      Apple        1    2   3   4   5
2      Banana       2    4   5   3   5
3      Potato       3    5   3   2   1
4      Tomato       1    1   1   1   1
5      Pear         $5    $5   $5   $5   $5
```

**My Code**:

```
df_transposed = df.set_index("Parameters").T.rename_axis('Fruits').reset_index()
df_transposed["Pear"] = df_transposed.Pear.mode()
df = df_transposed.set_index("Fruits").T.rename_axis('Parameters').reset_index()
```

I have a solution which works perfectly well with transposing the df and using `mode` on it and then re-transpose the data.

The point is it is too many steps. Just wondering if it can be done row wise also

Comment: In your data, are there actual dollar signs in front of the numbers?

Comment: @Erfan: Yes, there are signs before the number

Comment: But for all, or only for "Pear"?

Comment: @DanielMesejo: For all  the columns I want to do this exercise, in max there is a  `$` , but for very few they are just numbers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try slicing and `df.mode`. As you said you have so many columns to replace, you may filter columns base on columns NOT getting replaced.

```
cols = df.columns.drop(['Index', 'Parameters'])

df.loc[df.Parameters.eq('Pear'), cols] = df.loc[df.Parameters.eq('Pear'), cols].mode(axis=1)[0]


Out[77]:
   Index Parameters   A   B   C   D   E
0      1      Apple   1   2   3   4   5
1      2     Banana   2   4   5   3   5
2      3     Potato   3   5   3   2   1
3      4     Tomato   1   1   1   1   1
4      5       Pear  $5  $5  $5  $5  $5
```

Comment: How can I not name all the columns as I have way too many of them !!

Comment: @RahulAgarwal: In that case, you may filter columns base on those NOT getting replaced. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Worked Perfectly well, upvoted the answer!! One more query, if I want to do for 2 or more. For example Pear and Banana, would the solution change significantly or should i run this two times

Comment: @RahulAgarwal: The same logic, just change `eq` to `isin` as follows: `df.loc[df.Parameters.isin(['Pear', 'Banana']), cols] = df.loc[df.Parameters.isin(['Pear', 'Banana']), cols].mode(axis=1)[0]`